# Avoid function declaration in for loops for promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Eslint warns me not to define functions inside of for loops and I know it does so because it would define that function for every iteration which is obviously bad. However in my case I am not sure how I could rewrite the code so that this is not necessary anymore.

```
function refreshProfiles(job, done) {
  let isFinished = false
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // Get PlayerProfile promise and snapshot these
    const p = PlayerProfile.findOneAndUpdate(filter, updateDoc).then((profile) => {
      if (!profile) {
        isFinished = true
      }
      return refreshPlayerProfileIntoHistory(profile)
    }).catch((err) => {
      // Error handling
    })
    promiseArray.push(p)
  }

  return Promise.all(promiseArray).then(() => {
    // Recursive function call if we are not finished yet
    if (isFinished) {
      done()
    } else {
      // Recursive function call
      refreshProfiles()
    }
  })
}
```

**TL;DR what the code does:** It should stop with recursive function calls once it can't find profiles anymore.

**Question:**

How can I avoid defining the function in a for loop for this specific case where I would need to access a variable (the `isFinished` bool) which lives outside of the function I am defining in the loop?

Comment: Just a quick note, you can change your `if (!profile)` is redundant, just say `isFinished = !profile`

Comment: Why does your function take a `done` callback?

Comment: Eslint should stop bitching around, the usage of the callback functions is fine and doesn't have *that* much overhead. Of course you could trivially declare it outside of the loop, as it doesn't depend on `i`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Bergi it's the callback for the agenda job. https://github.com/agenda/agenda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `isFinished` flag and the function out of `refreshProfiles` and into the parent closure (so that both functions have access to it). Be sure to reset `isFinished` to `false` whenever the function is first called externally.

Comment: Then isFinished would be a kinda global variable, I am not sure if I really want that

Comment: It doesn't have to be. Depending on your architecture, it could be module scoped or a class instance property (e.g. `this.isFinished`). There are many ways you could encapsulate it, the key is just to move it out of that function and move it to somewhere mutually accessible.